# Does git affect on my express?

Tags: git, express

I am building simple express app and used `express generator`, and I want to put this on github.

I had `git commit` and noticed that it generate some lines on my `app.js` like `<<<<<<< HEAD` and some likely-hexanumbers.

I guess it is part of git but I wonder does it affect my application? Is it same as commenting??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will affect your application since `<<` doesn't comment in JavaScript. What you see means that there is a conflict between two different versions of the files. `<<<<<<< HEAD` points to the most recent commit of the current branch, while the hex value you see is the commit hash of the conflicting edit. To resolve this conflict, you must edit the file to contain the appropriate contents.

For more information, you can check out git's documentation. You may wish to look at [this](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/) article on GitHub.

Also, if you're new to git, I'd recommend checking out [GitHub's tutorial](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1). I'm not sure if it covers what you're experiencing, but it's a great way to get to know git.

Answer (score 2):

That's a merge conflict, and yes, it'll likely break your application in horrible ways if you leave it unreserved.

https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/